# Setting all properties of an object to same value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, lodash, forown

Having an object with this structure:

```
anObject = {
    "a_0" : [{"isGood": true, "parameters": [{...}]}],
    "a_1" : [{"isGood": false, "parameters": [{...}]}],
    "a_2" : [{"isGood": false, "parameters": [{...}]}],
    ...
};
```

I want to set all `isGood` values to `true`. I've tried using _forOwn to go through the object and forEach to go through each property but it seems it's not the correct approach.

```
_forOwn(this.editAlertsByType, (key, value) => {
    value.forEach(element => {
        element.isSelected = false;
    });
});
```

The error says:

> value.forEach is not a function

Comment: _forOwn from lodash/underscore? try _.forOwn (missing dot).
Also, what is `value`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

actually you were very close, you need to use `Object.keys()` to get the `keys` of your `anObject` object and then loop over them and finally modify each `array`.

```js
anObject = {
  "a_0": [{
    "isGood": true,
    "parameters": [{}]
  }],
  "a_1": [{
    "isGood": false,
    "parameters": [{}],
  }],
  "a_2": [{
    "isGood": false,
    "parameters": [{}],
  }],
  //...
};

Object.keys(anObject).forEach(k => {
  anObject[k] = anObject[k].map(item => {
    item.isGood = true;
    return item;
  });
})
console.log(anObject);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `forEach()` and `map()` on object `anObject`

```js
var anObject = {
    "a_0" : [{"isGood": true, "parameters": []}],
    "a_1" : [{"isGood": false, "parameters": []}],
    "a_2" : [{"isGood": false, "parameters": []}]
};

Object.keys(anObject).forEach((key)=>{
 anObject[key].map(obj => obj.isGood = true);
});

console.log(anObject);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this simple:

```
for (var key in anObject) {
  anObject[key]["isGood"] = true;
}
```

Comment: SO MUCH EASIER THAN OTHER SOLUTIONS !